# How do I fix error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity does not have a NavController..."?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have error when trying to get navController 
Here's part of my mainActivity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        navController = findNavController(R.id.activity_main_nav_host_fragment)
    }
}
```

I get error on line `navController = findNavController(R.id.activity_main_nav_host_fragment)`
Here's my logs:

```
2021-06-18 14:28:08.341 2564-2564/com.example.domains E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.domains, PID: 2564
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.domains/com.example.domains.ui.mainActivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.domains.ui.mainActivity.MainActivity@96d06d5 does not have a NavController set on 2131361863
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.domains.ui.mainActivity.MainActivity@96d06d5 does not have a NavController set on 2131361863
    at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.kt:50)
    at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:31)
    at com.example.domains.ui.mainActivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:43)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I think that something maybe wrong with my activity_main
So here's my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.mainActivity.MainActivity">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_nav_host_fragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/activity_main_nav_graph"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Why do I get an error and what way can I fix it? If you need more code, please, tell me what files I should show you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ---------  Answer -----------

**Follow the steps below:**

```
    private val navHostFragment =  supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.activity_main_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
   
     navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

After this you can use navcontroller.

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: Glad to help you. Could you please upvote this answer?